# Why instead of adding #include<linux/sched.h> in my code , the code cannot identify task_struct structure

Tags: c, linux, struct, operating-system, kernel

Below I have mentioned my small code and following are my queries regarding it -

1.I have opened /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32/include/linux/sched.h and I found the declaration of struct task_struct there , but when I try to declare an instance i.e variable of task_struct in the main function which includes the sched.h header , then also it is not able to identify the task_struct , Why ? , Why it is so
2. Even when I copied the complete code of that header file within my code i.e my .c file outside main class then the compiler shows error to include many other header files which was not a problem when I haven't copied the code of sched.h in my .c file

The Error being displayed by compiler in first case is - storage size of ‘temp’ isn’t known

My code is ( The code is just a representational view to tell my concept of Question)

```
#include<linux/sched.h>
int main(void)
{
    struct task_struct temp;
    printf("%d",temp.pid);
    return 0;
}
```

Since the concepts are clear still something is lacking, Kindly share your suggestions.

Comment: What do you want to use the variable `temp` for, in your real program. I'm asking because most probably there is better solution which doesn't need `struct task_struct` at all.

Comment: @pts , Today I am learning about process and while going through it I came to know that operating systems internally uses task_struct for storing the information related to a process and I just want to see them working via a C code

Comment: Let's suppose you figure out what to `#include`. Your program will still not work as intended, because you didn't initialize the the `temp` variable, so `temp.pid` contains garbage.

Comment: @Gaurav Joshi: The easiest way to see `struct task_struct` working in C code is writing a kernel module. Writing kernel modules is not easy at all for beginners, so you may want to find and read a tutorial first about writing Linux kernel modules, or ask somebody nearby (probably your professor) to walk you through the process on your laptop.

Comment: @pts , I thought that the instance of execution of my code (i.e my C code) would be the initialization for the task_struct because currently my process is being executed , I haven't thought of  garbage value , By the ways thanks for motivating me towards Kernal modules

Answer (score 2):

My Linux system (Ubuntu 14.04) doesn't make `struct task_struct` available to user code:

```
$ rgrep 'task_struct' /usr/include
/usr/include/linux/hdreg.h:} task_struct_t;
/usr/include/linux/capability.h:struct task_struct;
```

The 2nd match (`struct task_struct;`) is just a forward-declaration of the type. Without the `{ ... }` in the type declaration, it's just a forward-declaration, and in C (and C++) it's not possible to use a forward-declaration of a struct to create a variable of that type. That's why you are getting the `storage size of ... isn't known` error.

If you want to create a variable of type `struct task_struct`, you need to get its type declaration from another `.h` file, which has it with `{ ... }`. You may have to install a package containing kernel headers for this. Please refer to your Linux distribution's documentation about finding and installing packages. Once the package is installed, you can use `gcc -I /usr/.../...` to specify directory names for `gcc` to look for `.h` files.

Most programs (including all userland programs, excluding the kernel itself and excluding kernel modules) don't need to create a variable of type `struct task_struct` though. If you explain in your question what you want to use `struct task_struct` for, you'll probably get a recommendation to accomplish your goal without using `struct task_struct`.

If you just want to print the PID of the current process, here is how to do it without `struct task_struct`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
  printf("%lld\n", (long long)getpid());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey pts ! can you provide me a refernce link for the same

Comment: @GauravJoshi: I don't understand what you need a link for. Probably it's better to ask a separate StackOverflow question for that (e.g. how to find the `.h` file, how to install a package) if you aren't able to figure it out online.

Comment: @ptr , see u have put me in a dilemma , on  the one hand you are saying that Ubuntu 14.04 does not support task_struct to be in user's control on the contrary you are saying  to download a  kernel header for the same , when I am having the header i.e sched.h  which has declared task_struct within it , then what is the need of any other header

Comment: kindly help me out of this because you being the only person responded

Comment: My problem is that I want to see task_struct working as a C code in a similar way as my OS does , if possible

Comment: Yes I know the getpid() function but since operating internally uses the data structure of task_struct structure , so can I also use this structure to do  the same

Comment: @Gaurav Joshi: If you are writing a kernel module (to be loaded with `insmod` or `modprobe`), then you can use `struct task_struct` (and `current`), otherwise you can't. If you are not sure whether you are writing a kernel module, then you aren't. If you are not writing a kernel module, but you want to write one, look for online tutorials about writing a Linux kernel module, and if you get stuck, ask a separate question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Linux kernel headers are not designed to be included directly by user space programs. Even when you do this, this doesn't mean all content of such header is accessible to your code because of `__KERNEL__` definitions which prevent this to happen. Linux kernel still tries to make it possible though for user code to use kernel headers so sometimes it is possible to do this, but you should stick to use kernel headers in kernel code and use C library otherwise.

[This](https://lwn.net/Articles/113349/) article may help.

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this, `sched.h` is part of GNU

You can use like this:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#ifndef __USE_GNU
#define __USE_GNU
#endif
#include <sched.h>
```

Now you can use all functions of `sched.h`

Answer (score 0):

"struct task_struct" is undoubtedly present inside "linux/sched.h" . I suspect that you are building the module , in the wrong way , even your representational code looks like you are approaching the problem in user-space c programming style.
you should understand that Linux code is different from user space c programs in various aspects most basic being  that  it doesn't have  a conventional "main" function as an  entry point , but  registration based mechanisms.You can read about building kernel  modules from https://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html